# How has the mechanism of caste inheritance evolved with time in India?

Tags: india

Recent rulings have been that the child chooses from which side of the parent the caste he wants to take [(1)](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/children-of-inter-caste-couple-can-opt-for-caste-of-either-parent/article33815042.ece). Authoritatively, according to Hindu holy books, you can choose what caste you want to be by changing your actions and attitude [(2)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/any-references-where-varna-caste-is-determined-independent-of-birth-parentage).

It seems there has been a paradigm shift in how we viewed caste over the years. Especially before and after British rule. My question:

How has the mechanism of caste inheritance changed over the years? Generally, was the scripture's practice of one determine their caste by their actions followed throughout the history of India?

I'm mostly interested in the south side of Kerela.

[Relevant](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/what-was-the-origin-of-the-caste-system-in-india-and-how-did-it-proliferate)

Comment: See [history of the Indian caste system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caste_system_in_India#History).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this varies with what rule they were under, the location (Like South and North have quite different styles), the caste and the sub-caste they are in, etc. For Example, Kerala, parts of Tamil Nadu, and parts of Karnataka have a matrilineal inheritance. While most castes have a patrilineal system some do possess a matrilineal one even in the North and West. It's not gonna be easy to give a good and detailed answer unless it's narrowed down a bit.